# Horizontal WrapLayout shows elements vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I'm completely new to NativeScript but it looks like a sweet platform. I'm writing a toy app and below is my setup:

//code behind

```
import {AddExpenseModel} from "./add-expense-view-model";
import {EventData} from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import {Page} from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

let expenseModel = new AddExpenseModel();

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    let textField = page.getViewById("tags");

    textField.on("textChange", (ev)=>{expenseModel.onTagsTextFieldChange(ev)});
    page.bindingContext = expenseModel;
}

export function submit() {
    expenseModel.createNewExpense()
}
```

//view-model

```
import {Observable, PropertyChangeData} from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import {ObservableArray} from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";
let u = require('underscore');

export class AddExpenseModel extends Observable {
       ...

    public parsed_tags;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.parsed_tags = new ObservableArray([]);
        ...
    }

    public onTagsTextFieldChange(ev) {
        let that = this;
        // empty
        u.forEach(u.range(this.parsed_tags.length), function (_) {
            that.parsed_tags.pop()
        });

        let parsed = this.parseTags(ev.value);
        u.forEach(parsed, function (el) {
            that.parsed_tags.push(el);
        });
    }   

    private getParsedTags() {
        //unbox
        return u.map(this.parsed_tags, (el: string) => el)
    }

    private parseTags(tag_string) {

        let arr = u.map(tag_string.split(','), (tag: string) => tag.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());

        arr = u.uniq(arr);
        arr = u.filter(arr, u.negate(u.isEmpty))

        return arr;
    }
}
```

//view

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Add new expense"/>

        <text-field
                id="name" text="{{ name }}"
                row="0"/>
        <text-field id="amount" stext="{{ amount, amount | numberConverter }}" />

        <text-field id="tags" secure="false" text="{{ tags }}" 
        />
        <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" height="300" width="300">
            <ListView items="{{ parsed_tags }}">
                <ListView.itemsLayout>
                    <Label text="{{ $value }}" width="70" backgroundColor="red"/>
                </ListView.itemsLayout>
            </ListView>
        </WrapLayout>

        <button text="Add expense" id="submit-button" tap="submit"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

What I want to achieve is that when a user writes in the `tags` textfield,  stylised Labels appear in the `WrapLayout`. This works, however, the Labels appear always stacked **vertically**. Here's a screenshot
 [image]

I tried to move the whole WrapLayout section out of the StackedLayout section, but I get a `cannot read property 'on' of undefined, undefined`.
Putting Labels inside of WrapLayout not within a ListView (i.e. static) works as expected, which makes me thing I probably misuse either the ListView or the WrapLayout. Any directions will be appreciated :)

Cheers

**Update**
Following Eddy's advice I used a `Repeater`. Using the following xml

```
    <Repeater items="{{ parsed_tags }}">
        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" backgroundColor="#d3d3d3"/>
        </Repeater.itemsLayout>

        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ $value }}" backgroundColor="#84ddff" marginRight="5" marginLeft="5"/>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
```

correctly produces this:

[image]

I still don't see why using a ListView wouldn't work. I used the debugger from Sidekick and this is what I see.

```
    <ListView items="{{ parsed_tags }}">
        <ListView.itemsLayout>
            <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" backgroundColor="#d3d3d3" marginRight="5" marginLeft="5"/>
        </ListView.itemsLayout>

        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ $value }}" backgroundColor="#84ddff" marginRight="5" marginLeft="5"/>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: You're adding 1 child to the `WrapLayout` and that's a `ListView`, so it should indeed show the listview items vertically. Try replacing the listview by a simple repeater that outputs `Label` tags instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EddyVerbruggen! I got it to work using your advice about the Repeater. I saw that I mistakenly used the `itemsLayout` instead of the itemTemplate. Can you see the Update in the question - I'm still confused on the difference b/w the Repeater and the ListView.